# Is there any function in Perl similar to GetType() in C#?

Tags: perl

I have been learning Perl for a bit now and found it very different from other OOP languages I know. 
I tried to translate a C# code which goes like:

```
class Car{}, class CarList{}, class Program{}
```

and a method (pseudocode) :

```
if (var.GetType() == Car)
{
}
else if (var.GetType == CarList) 
{
}
```

how do I write this in perl without a GetType function or is there one?

Comment: Regardless of language, doing things this way rather than polymorphism is Bad OOP.

Answer (score 11):

In a lot of Perl code, the `ref` operator is what you want if you're seeking the exact name of the class of the object. Since it's undefined if the value is not a reference, you need to check the value before using string comparisons.

```
if(ref $var) {
    if(ref($var) eq 'Car') {
        # ...
    } elsif(ref($var) eq 'CarList') {
        # ...
    }
}
```

It's more likely that you want something like C#'s `is` operator. That would be the `isa` method of `UNIVERSAL` which is inherited by all objects. An example from the doc at http://perldoc.perl.org/UNIVERSAL.html:

```
use Scalar::Util 'blessed';

# Tests first whether $obj is a class instance and second whether it is an
# instance of a subclass of Some::Class
if ( blessed($obj) && $obj->isa("Some::Class") ) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: nice! `isa` much closer to GetType.

Answer (score 3):

[ref](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/ref.html) should be what you need.